# How to check if a function exists in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I need to find out if a function exists in a database, so that I can drop it and create it again. It should basically be something like the following code that I use for stored procedures:

```
IF EXISTS (
     SELECT  *
     FROM    dbo.sysobjects
     WHERE   id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_TEST]')
             AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1 )
```

Answer (score 233, accepted):

This is what SSMS uses when you script using the `DROP and CREATE` option

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM   sys.objects
           WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[foo]')
                  AND type IN ( N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT' ))
  DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[foo]

GO
```

This approach to deploying changes means that you need to recreate all permissions on the object so you might consider `ALTER`-ing if Exists instead.

Comment: Makes me wonder **even more** why [there isn't a sys.functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468672/sql-server-where-is-sys-functions) system catalog view.....

Answer (score 74):

I tend to use the Information_Schema:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
            FROM    Information_schema.Routines
            WHERE   Specific_schema = 'dbo'
                    AND specific_name = 'Foo'
                    AND Routine_Type = 'FUNCTION' )
```

for functions, and change `Routine_Type` for stored procedures

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
            FROM    Information_schema.Routines
            WHERE   Specific_schema = 'dbo'
                    AND specific_name = 'Foo'
                    AND Routine_Type = 'PROCEDURE' )
```

Comment: Cool I was looking for something like this and never found it.  I believe it is better to use information_schema in general as it is not tied to a specific RDBMS.  (btw the notion of being cross-platform compatible came from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14290099/420667)

Answer (score 62):

Why not just:

```
IF object_id('YourFunctionName', 'FN') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[YourFunctionName]
END
GO
```

The second argument of `object_id` is optional, but can help to identify the correct object. There are [numerous possible values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for this type argument, particularly:

- FN : Scalar function
- IF : Inline table-valued function
- TF : Table-valued-function
- FS : Assembly (CLR) scalar-function
- FT : Assembly (CLR) table-valued function
- U :  Table (user-defined)

Comment: Technically this can fail as it only checks that there is an object of that name. Not that there is an object and that it is a function. E.G. If `CREATE TABLE YourFunctionName(X INT);` then running the code will fail.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Easy to make robust. Just use `object_id('YourFunction', 'FN')` or any other designator (second argument) that makes it clear what kind of object you're referring to.

Comment: @darlove using 'FN' as second parameter may not work. I just learned. 'FN' means scalar function. This link tells you different parameters values you can pass http://sqlhints.com/tag/how-to-check-if-function-exists/. I keep using 'FN' to check for existing Table value function, and it does not work. I have to use 'TF'

Answer (score 17):

I know this thread is old but I just wanted to add this answer for those who believe it's safer to `Alter` than `Drop` and `Create`. The below will `Alter` the `Function` if it exists or `Create` it if doesn't:

```
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   sys.objects
               WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[foo]')
                      AND type IN ( N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT' ))
       EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[foo]() RETURNS INT AS BEGIN RETURN 0 END')
  GO
  ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[foo]
  AS
  ...
```

Comment: I like this, but I think it should be "ALTER FUNCTION", no?

Comment: I like `ALTER OR CREATE`

Answer (score 12):

I've found you can use a very non verbose and straightforward approach to checking for the existence various SQL Server objects this way:

```
IF OBJECTPROPERTY (object_id('schemaname.scalarfuncname'), 'IsScalarFunction') = 1
IF OBJECTPROPERTY (object_id('schemaname.tablefuncname'), 'IsTableFunction') = 1
IF OBJECTPROPERTY (object_id('schemaname.procname'), 'IsProcedure') = 1
```

This is based on the OBJECTPROPERTY function which is available in SQL 2005+.  The MSDN article can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx).

The OBJECTPROPERTY function uses the following signature:

```
OBJECTPROPERTY ( id , property )
```

You pass a literal value into the property parameter, designating the type of object you are looking for.  There's a massive list of values you can supply.

Comment: I think it would be easier to see the simplicity of this answer if it included a complete if/drop example.

Answer (score 2):

From SQL Server 2016 SP1, SQL Server 2017 or later, you can use the syntax:

```
CREATE OR ALTER [object] ...
```

To avoid jumping through these hoops. This has an additonal benefit of metadata about the procedure being persisted (rather than every time you change it it getting a brand new objectid) which can sometimes be useful, especially if you use things like QueryStore or other tools that care about the objectid.