# How to drop a table if it exists?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The table name is `Scores`.

Is it correct to do the following?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM   dbo.Scores)
  DROP TABLE dbo.Scores
```

Answer (score 1576, accepted):

> Is it correct to do the following?
>
> ```
> IF EXISTS(SELECT *
>           FROM   dbo.Scores)
>   DROP TABLE dbo.Scores
> ```

**No.**  That will drop the table only if it contains any rows (and will raise an error if the table does not exist).

**Instead, for a permanent table you can use**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Scores', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.Scores;
```

**Or, for a temporary table you can use**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempTableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #TempTableName;
```

SQL Server 2016+ has a better way, using `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS …`. See [the answer by @Jovan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33497857/73226).

Comment: Fwiw -- The `'U'` for the second param apparently means "Only look for objects with this name that are tables".  [One source](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10487/using-tsql-function-objectid.aspx).  So `OBJECT_ID('TableName')` isn't *wrong*, but it's not insanely precise either, thus `'U'` in @Martin's excellent answer.

Comment: Regarding the second param; [here is another source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) , I used 'V' for a View.

Comment: HI can you explain me what this second parameter means in OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#T', 'U'), for example this 'U' ?

Comment: @ZvonimirTokic it means "User defined Table". "IT" would be an internal, system defined, table. A full list is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx

Comment: Argh, my "one source" disappeared. [Archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120321203046/http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10487/using-tsql-function-objectid.aspx) & thanks, @TheRedPea for the second, more canonical, source.

Answer (score 583):

From SQL Server 2016 you can use

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Scores
```

Reference: [DROP IF EXISTS - new thing in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016)

It will be in SQL Azure Database soon.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for updating to current tech, @Jovan.

Comment: I rushed right out to use this when I found out it existed, but it still seems to wreak havoc on query plans, still true as of SQL Server 2019. When I switched from `IF OBJECT_ID() IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T_Foo` to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T_Foo`, otherwise identical stored procedures changed from 10 msec to 25 seconds! So make sure you measure performance if you use this new syntax.

Comment: DROP IF EXISTS is super buggy. Recommend avoiding.

Answer (score 162):

The ANSI SQL/cross-platform way is to use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx), which was specifically designed to query meta data about objects within SQL databases.

```
if exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'Scores' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
    drop table dbo.Scores;
```

Most modern RDBMS servers provide, at least, basic INFORMATION_SCHEMA support, including: [MySQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/information-schema.html), [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/information-schema.html), [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm), [IBM DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzmstcatalog.htm), and [Microsoft SQL Server 7.0 (and greater)](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20561).

Comment: Is the `if exists` ansi compliant?

Comment: Be careful if you have more than one schema in the database. You might need to be specific about which [Scores] you are detecting and deleting. E.g. WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Scores' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'

Comment: @kiquenet Generally yes, but not when using the if exists - since this stops as soon as it returns one row. But I personally always do select 1 anyway.

Answer (score 73):

Have seen so many that don't really work.
when a temp table is created it must be deleted from the tempdb!

The only code that works is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempdbname') IS NOT NULL     --Remove dbo here 
    DROP TABLE #tempdbname   -- Remoeve "tempdb.dbo"
```

Comment: Thanks, changing `dbo` to `tempdb` made this work.  I would also like to suggest adding the `'u'` as mentioned in the accepted answer's comments.  Thus, the full IF statement would look like this: `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp', 'U')`

Answer (score 54):

In SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and above

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Scores
```

In earlier versions

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Scores', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Scores;
```

***U*** is your `table type`

Answer (score 30):

Or:

```
if exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'Scores' and type = 'u')
    drop table Scores
```

Comment: You can use sys.tables since 2005 to simplify this: `if exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'Scores')
    drop table Scores`

Answer (score 28):

I hope this helps:

```
begin try drop table #tempTable end try
begin catch end catch
```

Answer (score 22):

I wrote a little UDF that returns 1 if its argument is the name of an extant table, 0 otherwise:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Table_exists]
(
    @TableName VARCHAR(200)
)
    RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    If Exists(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = @TableName)
        RETURN 1;

    RETURN 0;
END

GO
```

To delete table `User` if it exists, call it like so:

```
IF [dbo].[Table_exists]('User') = 1 Drop table [User]
```

Comment: What about same name but different schema? The best way is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33497857/956364

Answer (score 10):

Simple is that:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(dbo.TableName, 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.TableName
```

where `dbo.TableName` is your desired table and **'U'** is **`type`** of your `table`.

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server 2016 and above the best and simple one is
**DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [TABLE NAME]**

Ex:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Scores
```

if suppose the above one is not working then you can use the below one

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Scores', 'u') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Scores;
```

Comment: This adds nothing new to the existing answers

Answer (score 6):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Scores') AND TYPE in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE Scores
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

I use:

```
if exists (select * 
           from sys.tables 
           where name = 'tableName' 
           and schema_id = schema_id('dbo'))
begin
    drop table dbo.tableName
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use `cascade` constraint at the end to automatically drop all objects that depend on the table (such as views and projections).

```
drop table if exists tableName cascade;
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL Server syntax

Comment: And I believe (Microsoft) SQL Server is not the only SQL database out there. FYI, Vertica, Oracle, Snowflake, and PostgreSQL; all support CASCADE option. So, my answer complements yours and you didn't have to downvote me because of that.

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If you use long codes and want to write less for temporary table create this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MF_DROP (@TEMP AS VARCHAR(100)) AS
    EXEC('IF OBJECT_ID(''TEMPDB.DBO.' + @TEMP + ''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + @TEMP)
```

In execution:

```
EXEC MF_DROP #A
CREATE TABLE #A (I INT) ....
```

Answer (score -4):

A better visual and easy way, if you are using Visual Studio, just open from menu bar,

> View -> SQL Server Object Explorer

it should open like shown here

[image]

Select and Right Click the Table you wish to delete, then delete. Such a screen should be displayed. Click Update Database to confirm.

[image]

This method is very safe as it gives you the feedback and will warn of any relations of the deleted table with other tables.

Comment: This question is related to `SQL`, not related to `Visual Studio`. Therefore, this answer is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Btw, the question is "How to drop a table if it exists?" with a tag "sql-server" without specifically lining it to SQL only, therefore this answer is not only technically correct but some (knowing only basics) might find this more convenient and helpful instead.