# DROP IF EXISTS VS DROP?

Tags: sql, drop-table

Can someone tell me if there is any difference between

```
DROP IF EXISTS [TABLE_NAME]
```

```
DROP [TABLE_NAME]
```

I am asking this because I am using JDBC template in my MVC web application. If I use `DROP [TABLE_NAME]` the error said that Table exist. And if I use `DROP IF EXISTS [TABLE_NAME]` it says bad SQL grammar. Can some one help?

Comment: If you're looking for the SQL Server grammar, it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887011/how-to-drop-a-table-if-it-exists-in-sql-server

Comment: I think this should have a tag on question for what specific database.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Standard SQL syntax is

```
DROP TABLE table_name;
```

`IF EXISTS` is not standard; different platforms might support it with different syntax, or not support it at all. In PostgreSQL, the syntax is

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;
```

The first one will throw an error if the table doesn't exist, or if other database objects depend on it.  Most often, the other database objects will be foreign key references, but there may be others, too.  (Views, for example.)  The second will not throw an error if the table doesn't exist, but it will still throw an error if other database objects depend on it.

To drop a table, and all the other objects that depend on it, use one of these.

```
DROP TABLE table_name CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name CASCADE;
```

Use CASCADE with great care.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that it would be a **really** **good** idea for one to use `CASCADE` within a transaction block (`BEGIN` ... `COMMIT`). This way it is clear how the database will be affected _before_ potentially clobbering a bunch of data you may not have wanted to.

Comment: DROP IF EXISTS (without CASCADE) is also added in SQL Server 2016. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016.aspx

Answer (score 39):

It is not what is asked directly. But looking for how to do drop tables properly, I stumbled over this question, as I guess many others do too.

From SQL Server 2016+ you can use

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Table
```

For SQL Server <2016 what I do is the following for a permanent table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.Table;
```

Or this, for a temporary table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #T;
```

Answer (score 21):

You forgot the  `table` in your syntax:

```
drop table [table_name]
```

which drops a table.

Using

```
drop table if exists [table_name]
```

checks if the table exists before dropping it.
If it exists, it gets dropped.
If not, no error will be thrown and no action be taken.

Answer (score 4):

If no table with such name exists, `DROP` fails with error while `DROP IF EXISTS` just does nothing.

This is useful if you create/modifi your database with a script; this way you do not have to ensure manually that previous versions of the table are deleted. You just do a `DROP IF EXISTS` and forget about it.

Of course, your current DB engine may not support this option, it is hard to tell more about the error with the information you provide.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that some RDBMSs (PostgreSQL in particular) throw a warning if you try `drop some_table if exists;` and the table `some_table` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, and of course juegen d and Flakron are right. `DROP` needs that you specifiy the type of object (`TABLE` in this case)

Answer (score 4):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [table_name]
```

it first checks if the table exists, if it does it deletes the table
while

```
DROP TABLE [table_name]
```

it deletes without checking, so if it doesn't exist it exits with an error