# Correct way to drop a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to drop a table? The code I have does it two different ways. It will be dropped every week when I do a bulk insert. Thanks.

Like this?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM DBO.SYSOBJECTS
           WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[DBO].[ZIP]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(ID, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
    DROP TABLE [DBO].[ZIP]
```

Or this?

```
DROP TABLE DEID.DBO.ZIP
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.YourTable` seems like the easiest and safest way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method will throw an error if the table doesn't exist, or if other database objects depend on it.
The first one will not throw an error if the table doesn't exist, but it will still throw an error if other database objects depend on it.

Check out this answers on Stack-overflow:

- [DROP IF EXISTS VS DROP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565818/drop-if-exists-vs-drop)
- [How to drop a table if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887011/how-to-drop-a-table-if-it-exists)

Comment: Thanks. Should I just use DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  DEID.DBO.ZIP instead of the where statement?