# How can I continue past an error in a SQL script to execute other statements in the batch?

Tags: sql-server

I am using the New Query window in Visual Studio 2012 Server Explorer. Here
is the script I am trying to execute:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] DROP CONSTRAINT fk_UserId;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] DROP CONSTRAINT fk_RoleId;

DROP TABLE [dbo].[ExtraUserInformation];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Membership];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Roles];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExtraUserInformation] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [FullName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Link]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Verified] BIT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ExtraUserInformation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

There is currently no webpages_UsersInRoles table and it gives me an error
message saying:

```
Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Cannot find the object "dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

After this message the script seems to stop and it fails to create the other tables after this. Is there away that I can make the script continue after it passed the expected error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than continuing past the error is to test for the failure condition in the script, for example only dropping a table if it exists.

Instead of:

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles];
```

try:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887033/163495)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here, its really a matter of what you think is right for your script.

- You can put statements in try/catch blocks, and just swallow the error.
- You can do what SMO does when it generates T-SQL and wrap your statements in IF statements that ensure the object in question exists.
- You should be able to seperate out your 'sections' with GO statements, since these are sent as individual batches to the database.