# How do I delete a LocalDB database table if it exists

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am using entityFrameworks6 / POCO / code first.

Is there a simple way to delete a table if it already exists?

I have seen many similar questions but I cant get any to work. Probably cos they are for older versions.

The kind of think I'm looking for is...

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args)  {
        var db = new DatabaseContext2();

        //delete table - this doesnt work
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("drop if exists table myTableName");
```

Comment: this doesnt work - exceptions?

Comment: @GertArnold, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'". I dont think it supports "if exists" like mySQL does, I wrote that to indicate the type of thing I am after

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to drop a table if it exists in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887011/how-to-drop-a-table-if-it-exists-in-sql-server)