# SQL script working on SQL Fiddle, but not in MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have found a sample database in .sql format and I am trying to import it in MS SQL Server 2014 by running the script. If I run the contents of the file in SQL Fiddle (**[example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0565e/1)**), the script runs perfectly fine.

If I copy/paste the same code in Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and run it, I get syntax errors like this one:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
```

Any idea what's happening? I have been reading resolved questions, but I can't find an answer.

Code that I run in both SQL Fiddle and Microsoft SQL Server 2014:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.51, for pc-linux-gnu (i686)
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: world
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.51-debug-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES latin1 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `City`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `City`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` char(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CountryCode` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `District` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4080 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `City`
--
-- ORDER BY:  `ID`

INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (1,'Kabul','AFG','Kabol',1780000);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (2,'Qandahar','AFG','Qandahar',237500);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (3,'Herat','AFG','Herat',186800);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (4,'Mazar-e-Sharif','AFG','Balkh',127800);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (5,'Amsterdam','NLD','Noord-Holland',731200);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (6,'Rotterdam','NLD','Zuid-Holland',593321);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (7,'Haag','NLD','Zuid-Holland',440900);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (8,'Utrecht','NLD','Utrecht',234323);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (9,'Eindhoven','NLD','Noord-Brabant',201843);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (10,'Tilburg','NLD','Noord-Brabant',193238);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (11,'Groningen','NLD','Groningen',172701);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (12,'Breda','NLD','Noord-Brabant',160398);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (13,'Apeldoorn','NLD','Gelderland',153491);
```

Comment: MySQL is different from sql-server

Comment: there's no DROP IF EXISTS statement in MSSQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887011/how-to-drop-table-if-exists-in-sql-server-2005 check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Mysql syntax on sql server. You could do if exists as below in sql server:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.City', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.City
```

Also remove back ticks and remove engine type etc from create table.

```
CREATE TABLE City (
ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Name char(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
CountryCode char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
District char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
Population int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
);
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now. I though it's the same syntax.