# Issue with the IF EXISTS command

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to get this command that is on auto run to have an automatic delete incase I have to re-run the application. I am using visual studio and sql server 2012.

Here is what I have. The Create table works but its the IF EXISTS that I am having trouble with.

```
IF EXISTS (DROP TABLE ST_BANLIST)

CREATE TABLE ST_BANLIST
(BAN VARCHAR (9).
CALL_ACTIVITY CHAR(1).
BAN_STATUS CHAR(1))
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop a table if it exists in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887011/how-to-drop-a-table-if-it-exists-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax was incorrect:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ST_BANLIST', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.ST_BANLIST
```

SQL Server 2016 makes this a lot easier (what took so long Microsoft?):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.ST_BANLIST
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists(select * from  sys.objects where name ='MytableName' and type='U')
    Drop table dbo.MytableName
```