# Python try except to drop or create table in sql server

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I am using pyodbc to create or drop table. And I wrote a function to drop table if table has already existed. Please look at my syntax below

```
try:
    cur.execute('Drop table {}'.format(table_name))
except ProgrammingError:
    cur.execute(create_table)
```

However, I got error message :

```
<ipython-input-79-fe0fe29a1e8e> in upload_to_SQL(file_name, skiprows, table_name)
 26     try:
 27         cur.execute('Drop table {}'.format(table_name))
--->28  except ProgrammingError:
 29         cur.execute(create_table)
 30 

NameError: name 'ProgrammingError' is not defined
```

I confirm that **ProgrammingError** is the error message if I drop a table didn't exist in the sql server. Anyone have idea how to revise this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception you're getting is a `NameError`, because `ProgrammingError` isn't defined in the current scope.  `Exceptions` are objects just like everything else in python, and you have to import or reference them from the correct places.

You probably want to do

```
try:
    cur.execute('Drop table {}'.format(table_name))
except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
    cur.execute(create_table)
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Brendan Abel suggested, your exception `ProgrammingError` is out of scope. Make an `import` like :

```
from pyodbc import ProgrammingError
```

or

`pyodbc.ProgrammingError`. Also would be nice to change your query a bit:

```
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {}".format(self.table_name)
```

Here is a list [exceptions](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Exceptions) from `pyodbc` docs.

Comment: Thank you Anthony! I believe **Drop Table if exists** is not available in SQL server.

Comment: @Zed Fang, that's my mistake. Here is syntax for SQL server:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887011/how-to-drop-a-table-if-it-exists-in-sql-server#7887033)