# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF' when running a query in sqlserver

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to apply a query to a database which is responsible for creating the tables and filling it with data but it doesn't seem to work and always gives me

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
I'm not really good at SQL either to find the problem, so I hope if someone can help me figure out where the problem is located

Problem: the query should create tables and fill them with data
but it's not working and it's showing the error mentioned above which I dont 
know what it means and how to fix it

Thank you in Advance

The Query:

```
--  RESTAURANT DB
--  TABLE CREATION

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ORDER_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FOOD_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PAYMENT_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BILL_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CUSTOMER_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HOST_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CHEF_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS WAITER_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEE_t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MANAGER_t;


CREATE TABLE MANAGER_t
(
    ManagerID       INT             NOT NULL,
    M_Name          VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Salary          INT,

    CONSTRAINT MANAGER_PK PRIMARY KEY (ManagerID)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_t
(
    EmployeeID      INT             NOT NULL,
    E_Name          VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Date_hired      DATE,
    Hourly_pay      INT,
    ManagerID       INT             NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID),
    CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) REFERENCES MANAGER_t(ManagerID)
);

CREATE TABLE WAITER_t
(
    WaiterID        INT         NOT NULL,
    Tips            INT,

    CONSTRAINT WAITER_PK FOREIGN KEY (WaiterID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_t(EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE CHEF_t
(
    ChefID          INT         NOT NULL,
    Station         VARCHAR(10),
    Day_or_night    VARCHAR(5),

    CONSTRAINT CHEF_PK FOREIGN KEY (ChefID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_t(EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE HOST_t
(
    HostID          INT         NOT NULL,
    Tips            INT,

    CONSTRAINT HOST_PK FOREIGN KEY (HostID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_t(EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE_t
(
    TableNo         INT         NOT NULL,
    Available_seats INT,
    HostID          INT         NOT NULL,
    WaiterID        INT         NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (TableNo),
    CONSTRAINT TABLE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (HostID) REFERENCES HOST_t(HostID),
    CONSTRAINT TABLE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (WaiterID) REFERENCES WAITER_t(WaiterID)
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_t
(
    CustID          INT         NOT NULL,
    C_Name          VARCHAR(20),
    Phone           VARCHAR(10),
    TableNo         INT         NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY (CustID),
    CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_FK FOREIGN KEY (TableNo) REFERENCES TABLE_t(TableNo)
);

CREATE TABLE BILL_t
(
    BillNo      INT         NOT NULL,
    Amount      INT,
    CustID      INT         NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT BILL_PK PRIMARY KEY (BillNo),
    CONSTRAINT BILL_FK FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER_t(CustID)
);

CREATE TABLE PAYMENT_t
(
    PaymentNo   INT         NOT NULL,
    Amount      INT,
    Type        VARCHAR(8),
    CustID      INT         NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PAYMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (PaymentNo),
    CONSTRAINT PAYMENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES BILL_t(CustID)
);

CREATE TABLE FOOD_t
(
    FoodID      INT     NOT NULL,
    Name        VARCHAR(20),
    Price       INT,
    ChefID      INT     NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FOOD_PK PRIMARY KEY (FoodID),
    CONSTRAINT FOOD_FK FOREIGN KEY (ChefID) REFERENCES CHEF_t(ChefID)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER_t
(
    Order_time  TIME,
    CustID      INT     NOT NULL,
    WaiterID    INT     NOT NULL,
    FoodID      INT     NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER_t(CustID),
    CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (WaiterID) REFERENCES WAITER_t(WaiterID),
    CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (FoodID) REFERENCES FOOD_t(FoodID)

);



-- DATA INSERTION

-- INSERT INTO MANAGER_t VALUES (ManagerID, Name, Salary);
INSERT INTO MANAGER_t VALUES (1000, 'Suzie Smith',      55000);
INSERT INTO MANAGER_t VALUES (1001, 'Jerry Miller',     55000);
INSERT INTO MANAGER_t VALUES (1002, 'George Hill',      56000);
INSERT INTO MANAGER_t VALUES (1003, 'Elaine Scott',     60000);
INSERT INTO MANAGER_t VALUES (1004, 'Jim Kramer',       57000);
INSERT INTO MANAGER_t VALUES (1005, 'Michelle Garcia',  59000);



-- INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (EmployeeID, Name, Date_hired, Hourly_pay, ManagerID);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2000, 'Bill Williams',   '2016-05-31', 15, 1000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2001, 'Sarah Jenkins',   '2017-06-25', 16, 1000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2002, 'Jim Benvoglio',   '2017-07-21', 15, 1001);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2003, 'Chelsea Oldman',  '2018-04-20', 17, 1001);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2004, 'Andy Grandberg',  '2018-06-15', 15, 1001);



INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2010, 'Roberta Jones',   '2018-11-25', 25, 1002);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2011, 'Elfonzo Duke',    '2018-10-10', 20, 1002);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2012, 'Eric Brown',      '2016-09-23', 21, 1002);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2013, 'Izabel Frisk',    '2018-10-17', 23, 1003);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2014, 'Henri Menendez',  '2017-04-15', 25, 1003);


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2020, 'Sofia Gosselin',  '2016-04-18', 15, 1004);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2021, 'Don Ligma',       '2017-01-20', 15, 1004);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2022, 'Sarina Chastain', '2018-04-14', 16, 1004);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2023, 'Simonu Thomas',   '2018-03-05', 17, 1005);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_t VALUES (2024, 'Tom Cruz',        '2017-05-10', 17, 1005);



-- INSERT INTO WAITER_t VALUES (WaiterID, Tips);
INSERT INTO WAITER_t VALUES (2000, 30);
INSERT INTO WAITER_t VALUES (2001, 45);
INSERT INTO WAITER_t VALUES (2002, 50);
INSERT INTO WAITER_t VALUES (2003, 36);
INSERT INTO WAITER_t VALUES (2004, 42);




-- INSERT INTO CHEF_t VALUES (ChefID, Station, Day_or_night);
INSERT INTO CHEF_t VALUES (2010, 'Entrees', 'Day');
INSERT INTO CHEF_t VALUES (2011, 'Sides',   'Day');
INSERT INTO CHEF_t VALUES (2012, 'Entrees', 'Night');
INSERT INTO CHEF_t VALUES (2013, 'Sides',   'Night');
INSERT INTO CHEF_t VALUES (2014, 'Entrees', 'Day');



-- INSERT INTO HOST_t VALUES (HostID, Tips);
INSERT INTO HOST_t VALUES (2020, 27);
INSERT INTO HOST_t VALUES (2021, 35);
INSERT INTO HOST_t VALUES (2022, 33);
INSERT INTO HOST_t VALUES (2023, 40);
INSERT INTO HOST_t VALUES (2024, 43);



-- INSERT INTO TABLE_t VALUES (TableNo, Available_seats, HostID, WaiterID);
INSERT INTO TABLE_t VALUES (100, 6, 2020, 2000);
INSERT INTO TABLE_t VALUES (101, 8, 2021, 2001);
INSERT INTO TABLE_t VALUES (102, 6, 2021, 2002);
INSERT INTO TABLE_t VALUES (103, 8, 2020, 2001);
INSERT INTO TABLE_t VALUES (104, 2, 2022, 2000);
INSERT INTO TABLE_t VALUES (105, 4, 2022, 2002);


-- INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_t VALUES (CustID, Name, Phone, TableNo);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_t VALUES (3000, 'Dan Hamberg',     6175550123, 100);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_t VALUES (3001, 'Phil Ivan',       6175550101, 100);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_t VALUES (3002, 'Joan Johnson',    6175559021, 100);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_t VALUES (3003, 'Dani Doyle',      6175557821, 103);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_t VALUES (3004, 'Ben Xu',          9785557821, 103);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_t VALUES (3005, 'Paul Kay',        9785557821, 103);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_t VALUES (3006, 'Clif Wampler',    9785558211, 105);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_t VALUES (3007, 'Clem Williams',   9785556742, 105);


-- INSERT INTO BILL_t VALUES (BillNo, Amount, CustID);
INSERT INTO BILL_t VALUES (800, 35, 3000);
INSERT INTO BILL_t VALUES (801, 40, 3001);
INSERT INTO BILL_t VALUES (802, 22, 3002);
INSERT INTO BILL_t VALUES (803, 15, 3003);
INSERT INTO BILL_t VALUES (804, 16, 3005);
INSERT INTO BILL_t VALUES (805, 20, 3007);



-- INSERT INTO PAYMENT_t VALUES (PaymentNo, Amount, Type, CustID);
INSERT INTO PAYMENT_t VALUES (900, 35, 'Debit', 3000);
INSERT INTO PAYMENT_t VALUES (901, 40, 'Cash', 3001);
INSERT INTO PAYMENT_t VALUES (902, 22, 'Debit', 3002);
INSERT INTO PAYMENT_t VALUES (903, 15, 'Credit', 3003);
INSERT INTO PAYMENT_t VALUES (904, 16, 'Cash', 3005);
INSERT INTO PAYMENT_t VALUES (905, 20, 'Cash', 3007);



-- INSERT INTO FOOD_t VALUES (FoodID, Name, Price, ChefID);
INSERT INTO FOOD_t VALUES (200, 'Cheeseburger',     10, 2012);
INSERT INTO FOOD_t VALUES (201, 'Chicken Wings',    11, 2012);
INSERT INTO FOOD_t VALUES (202, 'Lobster Roll',     19, 2013);
INSERT INTO FOOD_t VALUES (203, 'Clam Chowder',      8, 2013);

INSERT INTO FOOD_t VALUES (204, 'French Fries',      6, 2014);
INSERT INTO FOOD_t VALUES (205, 'BLT',              10, 2014);
INSERT INTO FOOD_t VALUES (206, 'Caesar Salad',     10, 2010);
INSERT INTO FOOD_t VALUES (207, 'Veggie Burger',    12, 2010);



-- INSERT INTO ORDER_t VALUES (Order_time, CustID, WaiterID, FoodID);
INSERT INTO ORDER_t VALUES ('12:05:00', 3000, 2000, 200);
INSERT INTO ORDER_t VALUES ('15:45:00', 3001, 2000, 201);
INSERT INTO ORDER_t VALUES ('15:35:00', 3002, 2000, 202);
INSERT INTO ORDER_t VALUES ('14:15:00', 3003, 2001, 203);

INSERT INTO ORDER_t VALUES ('16:05:00', 3005, 2001, 202);
INSERT INTO ORDER_t VALUES ('17:25:00', 3004, 2001, 204);
INSERT INTO ORDER_t VALUES ('17:15:00', 3007, 2002, 206);
INSERT INTO ORDER_t VALUES ('18:35:00', 3005, 2001, 206);
```

Comment: Include the query in the stack overflow question. Include the MySQL version too. Read the manual for your MySQL version related to the SQL statement causing the problem. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-table.html

Comment: Hello, sorry about that. i included the code above, instead of the download link.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, I fixed my question. is there any other problem that is causing it to be on-hold?

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/7887011/2845389

Comment: Please decide what product you're using and fix the question to be consistent? Your title seems to imply SQL Server, but the question is tagged [tag:mysql], two distinctly different products.

Comment: Be aware that, *if* this is SQL Server, the `IF EXISTS` part of `DROP TABLE` was only added in the 2016 version. It won't work in lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your script has errors with **References** definition. I have attached the fixed constraint's code.

```
 CONSTRAINT HOST_PK FOREIGN KEY (HostID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_t(EmployeeID)
 CONSTRAINT TABLE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (HostID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_t(EmployeeID)
 CONSTRAINT TABLE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (WaiterID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_t(EmployeeID)
 CONSTRAINT FOOD_FK FOREIGN KEY (ChefID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_t(EmployeeID)
 CONSTRAINT ORDER_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (WaiterID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_t(EmployeeID)
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of a game of spot the difference, you could explain *what you've specifically changed* and why it fixes things? Because I'm looking at your references and failing to see what you've changed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever now you may have a look at exact changes. The **columns referenced with foreign key (in problem code) were themselves foreign keys**.

Answer (score 0):

DROP IF EXISTS construction works from SQL Server 2016.
Maybe the problem is that you are trying to execute your query on earlier version of SQL Server (or MySQL version)?