# How to find number of stored procedures, tables ,functions present in a Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to find number of stored procedures, tables ,functions  present in a Database?

Please help me finding the above.

Comment: If we use sys.objects or sysobjects, does it includes only user created objects or it includes system objects also???

Comment: sysobjects only includes user defined onjects.

Answer (score 6):

```
select count(*) 
from DatabaseName.information_schema.routines 
where routine_type in ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'TABLE')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sys.Tables` for the tables, `sys.procedures` for stored procedures and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468672/sql-server-where-is-sys-functions/468780#468780) for functions.

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype IN ('u', 'p', 'fn')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM user_objects  
WHERE object_name LIKE 'proc%' ....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM DB_Name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     * FROM   sysobjects  WHERE     (xtype = 'p')
```

You can get all the information from **sysobjects**