# Get the list of stored procedures created and / or modified on a particular date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to find which stored procedure I've created and also I want to find which stored procedure I've modified in my SQL Server on a particular date like 27 september 2012 (27/09/2012).

Is there any query which will list these procedures that are created and also modified on this date?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can try this query in any given SQL Server database:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    create_date,
    modify_date
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE create_date = '20120927'
```

which lists out the name, the creation and the last modification date - unfortunately, it doesn't record **who** created and/or modified the stored procedure in question.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please expans this answer by including how to hanlde it for user defined functions also?

Comment: @Lijo: [see my question "Why is there no `sys.functions` catalog view?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468672/sql-server-where-is-sys-functions) - the accepted answer shows you how to get the various types of functions from `sys.objects`

Answer (score 17):

Here is the "newer school" version.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' 
and CREATED = '20120927'
```

Comment: Could you provide any sources that state that using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` would currently be the preferred way (or "newer school")?

Comment: I didn't say "preferred".  "Newer", as in, it became available later in time.  And started with Sql Server 2005.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778%28v=sql.90%29.aspx      The one slight advantage would be if you deal with multiple RDBMS systems, then you're learning a standard, not a proprietary method.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema

Comment: The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` table has the `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` column (_which is the sql code of the stored procedure_), while `sys.procedures` doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
AND (DATEDIFF(D,modify_date, GETDATE()) < 7
     OR DATEDIFF(D,create_date, GETDATE()) < 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type='p' ORDER BY modify_date DESC

SELECT name, create_date, modify_date 
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'

SELECT name, crdate, refdate 
FROM sysobjects
WHERE type = 'P' 
ORDER BY refdate desc
```

Comment: Hi Abhik kashyap singh, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have a comment about your answer: your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT name, modify_date, create_date, type
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE name like '%XXX%' 
ORDER BY modify_date desc
```