# How to view a stored function - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-functions

Version: SQLServer 8

I would like to view the contents of a stored function in sqlserver, i.e. what exactly the function is doing.

None of the options listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468672/sql-server-where-is-sys-functions) work for me. There doesn't appear to be any database/table called sys.objects. I was able to query the information_table.routines table, but that does not contain the function that I am looking for. My function is located in:

DBName.dbo.functionName

How can I view the contents of this function?

Comment: Why dont you use Management Studio or you certainly want to check with query?

Comment: @Rolice I want to check with a query because I am on Linux and none of the solutions I've found allow me to view the function directly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [sp_helptext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176112.aspx) command to view the definition. It simply does

> Displays the definition of a user-defined rule, default, unencrypted Transact-SQL stored procedure, user-defined Transact-SQL function, trigger, computed column, CHECK constraint, view, or system object such as a system stored procedure.

E.g;

`EXEC sp_helptext 'StoredProcedureName'`

**EDIT:**
If  your `databases` or `server` are different then you can do it by specifying them as well

```
EXEC [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_helptext 'storedProcedureName'
```

Comment: How can I run this when the current database is different from the target database? When I'm connected to the default database and run the above command, I get: `Error code 15250, SQL state S0001: The database name component of the object qualifier must be the name of the current database.` This works only when currently connected to DBName: `EXEC sp_helptext 'DBName.dbo.functionName'`

Comment: try this `EXEC  [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_HelpText 'storedProcName`

Comment: That worked! I didn't need the server name part, though. `EXEC [DatabaseName].dbo.sp_helptext '[functionName]'`

Answer (score 12):

```
select definition 
from sys.sql_modules 
where object_name(object_id) like 'functionName'
```

Comment: you can use `like '%routineName%'` or `= 'routineName'`

Comment: Note that this table does not store all types of functions.  Per the doc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx), it includes sprocs, replication filter procedures, views, SQL DML triggers, scalar functions, TVFs, and rules.  That excludes all CLR functions, CLR triggers, constraints, and extended stored procedures.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! This worked for functions (Not just stored procedures) and totally saved me. <3

Answer (score 2):

```
--ShowStoredProcedures
select p.[type]
      ,p.[name]
      ,c.[definition]
  from sys.objects p
  join sys.sql_modules c
    on p.object_id = c.object_id
 where p.[type] = 'P'
   --and c.[definition] like '%foo%'
ORDER BY p.[name]
___________

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) ProcedureName,
       definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE objectproperty(object_id,'IsProcedure') = 1
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
```

Comment: this is much better than the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is working fine.

To view the stored procedures...
SELECT * FROM sys.procedures;

and get procduere name and use the below query for the same(I'm using SQuirreL SQL Client Version 3.2.0-RC1).

EXEC sp_helptext 'StoredProcedureName'.

Answer (score 1):

I rather use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES:

```
select ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION, LAST_ALTERED 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where SPECIFIC_NAME = 'usp_mysp'
```

Just copy the ROUTINE_DEFINITION column to a new window to see the full content.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is Stored Procedure OR Function OR any SQL object below script will give the full definition

```
USE<Your Data base>
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID('<YOUR OBJECT NAME>')) AS ObjectDefinition
```

where **OBJECT NAME** could be your object name such as Stored Procedure / Function / Trigger ...etc name

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Object Explorer, choose the Database containing the Stored Procedure and then choose 'Script Stored Procedure  As ':

[image]

And then check in the destination folder you chose.