# is there any way to get the list of the inbuilt function of the sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT *
FROM sysobjects
WHERE xtype='p'
```

above query will give us the list of all procedures in the database, in the same way
how can I get the list of internal functions?

Comment: You mean, outside the documentation which has a list AND actually a description of them? What is your use case?

Comment: What do you mean by internal function? Not user-defined?

Comment: You mean these?? [Built-in Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318.aspx)

Comment: Those will be listed under every database, `Programmability -> Functions -> System Functions`

Comment: you are right but i want to get the list of them thru query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468672/sql-server-where-is-sys-functions

Comment: @user3129402 Please accept answer if it solves your problem . Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.You have never accepted any answers in any of your questions . Is not a good practise . [Please read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/246945)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT name, definition, type_desc 
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE type_desc like '%function%'
```

Or else:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects where type in ('FN','AF','FS','FT','IF','TF')
```

Here are the types:

```
--AF = Aggregate function (CLR)
--C = CHECK constraint
--D = DEFAULT (constraint or stand-alone)
--F = FOREIGN KEY constraint
--PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint
--P = SQL stored procedure
--PC = Assembly (CLR) stored procedure
--FN = SQL scalar-function
--FS = Assembly (CLR) scalar function
--FT = Assembly (CLR) table-valued function
--R = Rule (old-style, stand-alone)
--RF = Replication filter procedure
--SN = Synonym
--SQ = Service queue
--TA = Assembly (CLR) trigger
--TR = SQL trigger 
--IF = SQL inlined table-valued function
--TF = SQL table-valued function
--U = Table (user-defined)
--UQ = UNIQUE constraint
--V = View
--X = Extended stored procedure
--IT = Internal table
```

**[Built-In Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318.aspx)**