# Is there a system table or system view that lists all built-in functions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I am building an application with which users can create their own user-defined functions in a SQL Server database. I have to validate in some way that the function name picked by the user does not equal to the name of a built-in function (such as avg, concat, ...) since this would break the application.

Is there a way to query the names of all **built-in functions** (not the UDFs), such as a system view or any the like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there any way to get the list of the inbuilt function of the sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289458/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-list-of-the-inbuilt-function-of-the-sql-server)

Comment: That wouldn't give you things like `CONCAT`, `AVG`, @SurajKumar . Honestly, what the OP describes sounds like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) and an injection nightmare.

Comment: @Larnu Retracted the close vote now.

Comment: Users creating their own functions....what could go wrong?? Honestly this idea is just horrifying.

Comment: @Larnu As for security reasons I can see your point and I am very much aware of the issues that are coming along, but that does not really help me to find an answer. I know that the SQL Server Management Studio can list all system functions in the object explorer, so there has to be some way to query them

Comment: None of the system views give you this information, no. If you need a list, you'd be better of making your own white list. But either way, like myself and Sean said, this sounds like a terrible idea and likely what you say you want here to achieve isn't what you really want.

Comment: It's in fact not mandatory for what I essentially want to archive, but it would have been the only way without a significant chage of concept. But if there is no way to get this information from a system view or similar, I guess I will have to go back to 'Problem X'

Comment: Instead of checking that, you can enforce some naming conventions, e.g. must have special prefix to the function name, Then you can check that prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is YOUR rule of naming functions, as long as YOU are the developer. Which means your functions will have always your prefix in database, as `mf_`  which could mean **m**`y`**f**`unction_` and your user's function name. In your code always put that `mf_` prefix in front of your user's function call, check if it exists and use it.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way around prefixes but since there is no such system table of built-in functions or similar, I guess using prefixes is the only way that works.